# SQL concatenate text fields from different records in the same file

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

Were talking about data in a file on an iSeries here using DB2.

File structure is as such:

```
Item     Textline    Text

12755    1           this item
12755    2           is no longer
12755    3           for sale
abc123   1           please use
abc123   2           another code
xyz987   1           obsolete
```

The result im trying to get is

```
   Item     Text

   12755    this item is no longer for sale
   abc123   please use another code
   xyz987   obsolete
```

So it is grouped by Item code and the text lines are added up regardless of how many there are.

I tried it in query first by joining the file to itself 5 times (there can be as many as 5 text lines) but i could never get it to work.

I tried it in SQL but i cant get the commands im familair with to work correctly with text and im struggling on the criteria to add them together without duplicating the text lines up.

Anyone any idea's ?

My last resort is to extract this file 5 times over itself with each file just containing a different text line and then matching them all back together based on item and concatenating that way... but wow how messy that is :)

Please help :)

Comment: My first thought was `GROUP_CONCAT` but it appears that DB2 doesn't have that. Some Googling gave me this article on an alternative for `GROUP_CONCAT` for DB2 that I think might be what you need: http://radheshk.blogspot.nl/2008/02/sql-tips-techniques-string-aggregation.html You'll have to work in an `ORDER BY Textline` yourself :)

Comment: Thanks funkwurm. I'll have a blast at that on Monday morning. I just refuse to have to split the file into 5 individual files just to bunch them back into 1 again. Seems so poor! :)

Comment: @funkwurm When Googling for DB2 answers, it often pays to notice which DB2 platform the article pertains to.  In this case your answer is for DB2 LUW (Linux, Unix, Windows).  Fortunately the linked page describes a solution that should work on DB2 for i, but the other suggested links found there will not.

Answer (score 6):

DB2 for i can do this.

Perhaps the most concise way is to use an often overlooked feature, that the other DB2 platforms do not have -- a type of recursive query known as a [hierarchical query](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzhierquerycl.htm).  Like many things, it's fairly simple once you understand it, but it deserves a bit of explaining to understand how it works.

A recursive or hierarchical query helps you connect one row to one or more others.  In this case we are making a chain of one to one connections.

The aggregate [SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH function](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzscasys_cby_path.htm) will concatenate strings along the path from a starting (or "root") row to the end (or "leaf") row.

Let's start by putting your sample data into a table.

```
declare global temporary table snippets
( item    varchar(10)
, seq     smallint
, words   varchar(30)
);

insert into snippets  
  values 
   ('12755',  1, 'this item')
  ,('12755',  2, 'is no longer')
  ,('12755',  3, 'for sale')
  ,('abc123', 1, 'please use')
  ,('abc123', 2, 'another code')
  ,('xyz987', 1, 'obsolete')
;
```

Let's look at the hierarchical query we will use as a first phase building block.

```
 SELECT item
      , seq
      , CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF as flag
      , SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(words, ' ') as phrase
   FROM snippets
   START WITH seq = 1
   CONNECT BY PRIOR item = item and PRIOR (seq + 1) = seq
```

The [CONNECT BY](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzcbyroot.htm) clause defines the join conditions from one row in the table to another.

The [START WITH](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzhierquerycl.htm) clause specifies which row(s) to begin joining from, the "root" row. So we are going to start with rows where seq=1, and join to the next seq value (seq+1).  That row will join to the following seq value, and so on.

[CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzpseudocol.htm) will indicate when we are at the last row in the chain.  You'll in a moment why I used it here.

Here are the results:

```
    ITEM   SEQ  FLAG  PHRASE

    12755   1    0    this item
    12755   2    0    this item is no longer
    12755   3    1    this item is no longer for sale
    abc123  1    0    please use
    abc123  2    1    please use another code
    xyz987  1    1    obsolete
```

Now all we need to do is put that in a [common table expression](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzcomtexp.htm), 
from which we can take only the rows we want.  The "leaf" rows at the end of the chain have the completed string, so those are the ones to pick.

```
with q as
(
  SELECT item
       , seq
       , CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF as flag
       , SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(words, ' ') as phrase
    FROM snippets
    START WITH seq = 1
    CONNECT BY PRIOR item = item and PRIOR (seq + 1) = seq
)
SELECT item
     , phrase
  FROM q
  WHERE flag = 1
  ORDER BY item
;
```

Which gives us:

```
    ITEM     PHRASE

    abc123   please use another code    
    xyz987   obsolete   
    12755    this item is no longer for sale
```

There you have it.

Folks on other DB2 platforms will have to find another solution, such as a regular recursive query in [funkworm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684660/funkwurm)'s comment above.

Comment: Wow ! @warrenT that is one hell of a comprehensive answer. Thank you very much :) 

Trouble is i get this error with it. I'm stabbing at it now trying to figure out why:
Message . Keyword START not expected. Valid tokens: ) FETCH ORDER UNION EXCEPT. Cause . .:The keyword START was not expected here. A syntax error was detected at keyword START. The partial list of valid tokens is ) FETCH ORDER UNION EXCEPT. This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the unexpected keyword.  The error may be earlier in the statement but the syntax of the statement seems to be valid up to this point.

Comment: What release are you on?  I pasted the code directly from my Navigator SQL window, where it worked fine on an up to date v7.1 system, and gave the results shown.

Comment: Worked for me like a charm on v7 too, awesome!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a User-defined function that can do this sort of thing, here's one I wrote to accomplish an essentially identical task:

```
create function GetTextBlock(inItemNo decimal(13,0))
returns varchar(1200)
begin atomic
    declare outstr varchar(1200) default '';
    for list_comments as
            select tltx60
            from msytxl
            where tlcono = 1 
              and tldivi = '' 
              and tltxid = inItemNo 
            order by tllino
    do
            set outstr = outstr || trim(tltx60) || ' ';
    end for;
    set outstr = rtrim(outstr);
    return outstr;
end
go
```

Then you can use it in a SELECT statement like so:

```
Select ItemNo, GetTextBlock(ItemNo)
from ItemMaster
```

(This code was written for, and works on, DB2 for i V6R1)

Answer (score 1):

V5R4

```
declare global temporary table qtemp.snippets
( item    varchar(10)
, seq     smallint
, words   varchar(30)
);

insert into qtemp.snippets  
  values 
   ('12755',  1, 'this item')
  ,('12755',  2, 'is no longer')
  ,('12755',  3, 'for sale')
  ,('abc123', 1, 'please use')
  ,('abc123', 2, 'another code')
  ,('xyz987', 1, 'obsolete')
;

with q(item, seq, words, phrase) as
(
    SELECT s.item
       , s.seq
       , s.words
       , s.words phrase 
    FROM qtemp.snippets s
    where s.seq = 1
    union all 
    SELECT s1.item
       , s1.seq
       , s1.words
       , q.Phrase || ' ' || s1.words phrase  
    FROM qtemp.snippets s1
    join q on s1.item = q.item
        and s1.seq = q.seq +1
)
select q.item, q.phrase from q 
join (
Select q.item, max(q.seq) maxseq from q
group by item
 ) q1 on q.item = q1.item and q.seq = q1.maxseq
```

Answer (score 0):

[DB2 for i](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzintro.htm) does not have an [aggregate function](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzcolfunc.htm) that could be used for this purpose nor does it support user defined aggregate functions.

The only options are a stored procedure or 'client' side aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

@WarrenT -- after some 16+ years on the i, I thought I was one of those cats... but you have disturbingly proved me wrong. :) Great response on the SQL. And yes, I see a few opportunities to use it right away!!!

Unfortunately, I am limited to V5R4... will that work as a stored procedure call from, say a .NET web app?