# SQL query to select one of multiple rows from a table

Tags: sql, join, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a table which contains more than one row for a particular value . Here is the table structure:

```
NAME,NUMBER,STATUS,DESC,START_DATE,END_DATE
A,3,X,DetailsOfX,13-10-15,13-10-15
A,2,Y,DetailsOfY,13-10-15,13-10-15
A,2,Z,DetailsOfZ,13-10-15,13-10-15
A,1,X,DetailsOfX,12-10-15,12-10-15
```

The output i need is i.e.

```
A,3,X,DetailsOfX,13-10-15,13-10-15
A,2,Y,DetailsOfY-DetailsofZ,13-10-15,13-10-15
A,1,X,DetailsOfX,12-10-15,12-10-15
```

So basically i want to select one of two or more rows from a table with data from columns from both the rows (in bold above). The query below i tried using JOIN returns 4 rows.

```
SELECT A.NAME,A.NUMBER,B.STATUS,A.DESC||"-"||B.DESC,A.START_DATE,A.END_DATE
FROM TABLE A
JOIN (SELECT NUMBER,STATUS,DESC,START_DATE,END_DATE FROM TABLE WHERE NAME='A') B
ON A.NAME=B.NAME AND
A.NUMBER=B.NUMBER
```

Can somebody help me with the query that would work.

Thanks

Comment: This will vary heavily depending on the RDBMS that you are using.

Comment: I don't think you'd be needing a JOIN in this case.

Comment: It is AS400 at backend

Comment: You'd probably want to add an `AND A.STATUS <> B.STATUS`, otherwise you'll just be self-joining rows on themselves and end up with `DetailsOfY-DetailsOfY`

Comment: The table has a lot more rows for NAMEs other than A. Adding this <> condition is omitting all other rows and still give me 2 rows out of which one is exactly i want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IBM i 7.1 (formerly known as OS/400), you should be able do this with two tricks:  [hierarchical queries](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzhierquery.htm), and [XML functions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzasp%2Frbafyxml3909.htm).

See [my tutorial under Q: SQL concatenate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536169/sql-concatenate-text-fields-from-different-records-in-the-same-file/18543217#18543217) which explains how to do this on DB2 for i  in order to merge the descriptions.

`GROUP BY` any fields by which you would want rows combined into one, but all other columns must be the result of an aggregate function.  So for example, if you want one row per name, number, but have various values for Status, StartDate, EndDate, then you will need to say something like `min(Status), min(StartDate), max(EndDate)`.  Is the minimum status code actually the one you want to report?

If your OS is at version 6.1, you may still be able to use a conventional [recursive query](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzcomtexp.htm) (or [under v5r4](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzmstintsel.htm)), but you might need an addtional CTE (or two?) to concatenate the descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY` and `FOR XML PATH`:

```
SELECT 
  X.NAME, X.NUMBER, X.STATUS,
  STUFF((
    SELECT '-' + [Desc] AS Desc 
    FROM YourTable Y
    WHERE Y.ID = X.ID
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE),1,1,'') AS DescValues,
  StartDate,
  EndDate
FROM YourTable X
GROUP BY Name, Number, Status, StartDate, EndDate
```

This is assuming you want separate rows for any differences in name, number, status, start date, or end date.

Also, this is assuming SQL Server.

Comment: I have AS400 at backend. Not sure if this would help. Thanks.

Comment: No, this will not work on DB2 for i.  Our syntax, and our support for XML is different.  (On SQL Server, wouldn't your query put a hyphen in front of every description, whether concatenated or not?)